# Moving graph/Chart to specific location with VBA in MS WORD 2013

Tags: vba, graph, location, bookmarks

I generated a graph using VBA and I have one specific bookmark in current word document. my challenge is to move the generated graph to the bookmark location. 
I searched a lot but in vain.

Can any body help me in getting VBA code for this. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Please add some code and let us see what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with this to get the desired size/position

```
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
     .Height = 325 ' set height
     .Width = 500 ' set width
     .Top = 100 ' Top position
     .Left = 200 ' Left position
End With
```

I would suggest, just guessing at the top and left position with trial and error to figure out the exact position you need it in.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I know how to generate a graph and I did that. my challenge is once I generate it, I need to move it to a place where there is a bookmark.

Comment: I updated my response. Check to see if you can make something like this work.